# autotools install headers only when newer

Tags: installation, autoconf, automake

I want to configure my autotools build so header/data files only get installed when they are newer than a file already installed.

On Linux, makefiles get INSTALL = /usr/bin/install, on Solaris INSTALL = install-sh. Both take a -C parameter that should do what I want, but I don't see any examples of AC_PROG_INSTALL, or other macro, that show how this gets configured to use the -C.

Is there an elegant method, or do I result to something ugly?

Comment: It feels like this is a decision best left to the user.  The user can always specify INSTALL at configure time to include -C, or can put it in a config.site.

Comment: Would work, but I'm looking to reduce developer compile times during development. I.e., change one header in a lib, and re-install it, and all header timestamps in that lib change. If the lib is common, then the project wants to re-compile everything.  Want to avoid that.

Comment: So when the developer is the user, have the developer configure with -c in INSTALL.

Comment: @CAB: When your improvements are aimed at a certain (small!) subset of your total user base, you break the principle of least surprise for everyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like William mentioned in his comments, a clean solution is to overwrite INSTALL during configure time.

If you do not want `make install` to touch the files in `$PREFIX` unless needed use `install -C`.

```
$ ./configure INSTALL="install -C"
```

If you you want to avoid rebuilding targets due to changed creation times of headers,  preserve timestamps of files with

```
$ ./configure INSTALL="install -p"
```